# ASP.NET Error when trying to access page

Tags: asp.net

Im getting this odd error:

Any help would be great?

**This is the error:**

> ### Server Error in '/Rugby' Application.
>
> **Configuration Error**
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file  appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> Line 33:
> Line 34:
> Line 35:    <roleManager enabled="true">
> Line 36: 
> Line 37:       <providers>
> ```
>
> **Source File:** C:\Websites\ADHS\andyhollis.co.uk\rugby\admin\web.config
>   **Line:** 35
>
> Show Additional Configuration Errors:
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> (C:\Websites\ADHS\andyhollis.co.uk\rugby\admin\web.config
>   line 43)
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> (C:\Websites\ADHS\andyhollis.co.uk\rugby\admin\web.config
>   line 67)
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

Comment: @Andy: you may want to include the error message in your question so this question will be useful after your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because you've accidentally uploaded a web.config to a non-root directory, or because the directory containing the web.config isn't configured as an application root.

Answer (score 3):

This sometimes happens when you have a Web.config in a subdirectory of the application's root.

Alternatively, you may need to go into the virtual directory and configure it correctly as an application (as noted by the error message).

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the error message:
"This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Configure it as an application, and it will be fine.

IIS 5/6:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx

IIS 7:
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/12/Creating-IIS7-sites_2C00_-applications_2C00_-and-virtual-directories.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Basically, ASP.NET allows for hierarchical configuration files, starting from machine.config and numerous security based web.config files tucked away in the framework's config folder, and then going from the root of your web application down the subfolders.

However, some elements can only be overriden in the root web.config for each application. These include (but aren't limited to):

- Authentication
- Profile
- RoleManagement
- SecurityPolicy
- SiteMap

The full list of web.configuration elements can be [found under here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx), and each one has a section **Element Information**, with a subsection "Configurable locations". If it says "Virtual or physical directory–level Web.config" then you can have the element anywhere.

As this is presumably the admin screens of your application, you probably don't want to make the directory an application in it's own right - if you do you'd lose access to the main application below it, which isn't what you'd want, and you'll possibly also have to have a seperate /bin folder under there with the admin .dll in.

You would be better off configuring the RoleManagement in the root web.config of your site, (either at / or if Rugby is an application, then at /Rugby) and only having the elements you need to be different (e.g. the autherization element to lock out users) in the web.config in /Rugby/Admin.

For example, on one of my sites, the web config in the admin folder is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <!-- Allow users in role "Editor" -->
      <allow roles="Editor" />
      <!-- Block everyone else -->
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error you didn't post has changed. Now it's "500 Internal Server Error". That usually means an unhandled exception. Look in the Windows Event Log to see what happened.